Prove that $x^6 + 5x^2 + 8$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$.
This question has already been asked on Mathematics Stack Exchange 5 months ago by the user @JAYENDRA JHA. This is one of the answers given to the problem -

()=$^6+5^2+8$  is irreducible. You can ask WolframAlpha to factor the polynomial mod for small primes  (each of these is a finite computation so in principle you could do this yourself by hand). You get


() ≡ $(^3+^2+2+1)(^3+2^2+2+2) \ mod \ 3$


$() ≡ (^2+2)(^2++2)(^2+4+2)\ mod \ 5$


and this is already enough to show that () is irreducible! This is because if it were reducible it would have to have an irreducible factor of degree 1, 2, or 3, and the first calculation rules out the possibility of degrees 1 or 2, while the second calculation rules out the possibility of degree 3 (since a degree 3 factor would either remain irreducible or have at least one degree 1 factor mod $\\$ 5).


WolframAlpha will also tell you that () is irreducible mod29 although this would be quite a bit more annoying to verify by hand. Instead of doing the mod5 computation you can also observe that () has no real roots, meaning its irreducible factorization over ℝ must be as a product of 3 irreducible quadratics.

I cannot understand what they mean  by "the first calculation rules out the possibility of degrees 1 or 2, while the second calculation rules out the possibility of degree 3."   Saying that factorisation mod $3$ rules out the possibility of a degree 2 factor seems wrong (see Q2).
I have spent a lot of time trying to understand the connection but I am not able to come up with a satisfactory explanation on my own and Google searches on the topic don't yield useful results either. So my questions are -
Q1. What does the factorisation of a polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$ has to do with anything with its factorisation mod $p$?
Q2. It is easy to see that $f(x) = x^6 + 5x^2 + 8$ ≥ 8 for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. It can be verified using Rational Root Theorem that $f(x)$ does not have any linear factors, and since all cubics have at least one real root, $f(x)$ cannot have a cubic factor, which means that it has to be a product of three quadratics. How can we prove that there exists no such three quadratics with integer coefficients that multiply to give $f(x)$ ?
Any help on the topic would be appreciated!
EDIT - This is the link to the original post -> Prove that $x^6+5x^2+8$ is reducible over Z (integer)?

If there is a factorization over Z, do you see how to get a factorization over Z_p? (Only in that direction) $\quad$ Note that We do still have to show that those terms in Z_3 and Z_5 are irreducible.  $\quad$ Can you link to the post?

If f(x)=a(x)b(x) over Z then f(x)=a(x)b(x)  over the integers modulo p. The first factorisation, for example,  shows that it has no linear factor mod 3 and therefore no linear factor over Z.  Does that help?

Can you elaborate on your statement @user1172706? Suitably with an example?

$k[x]$ is UFD. You can not have two "different" factorizations. I think this is the idea.

The irreducible factors over $\mathbb Z$ have to be combinations of the factors obtained over $\mathbb Z_p$ - reducing modulo $p$ cannot change the factors, apart from splitting the factors over $\mathbb Z$ into sub-factors.

@MarkBennet, can there be multiple factorisations mod $p$ for a polynomial?

AN EXPLANATION AS ASKED FOR BY THE OP
Consider $x^3+x^2+x+1$. Over the integers this factorises as $(x+1)(x^2+1)$.
The crucial fact is that this factorisation holds over all mod $p$ as well. But sometimes an extra factorisation will take place.
So, for example, modulo 5 we have $(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)$.
YOUR PARTICULAR EXAMPLE
The first factorisation mod 3 tells you that over the integers the only possibilities are for the polynomial to be irreducible or the product of two cubics.
If it was the product of two cubics then mod 5 each of these cubics would either be irreducible or have a linear factor. There are no linear factors mod 5 and so the cubic is indeed irreducible over the integers.

Does this "method" of proving irreducibility have a name? I think I need to do some more examples to really get a hang of it.

I don't know a specific name except for "modular factorisation" but you can use an online resource such as https://planetcalc.com/8332/ to quickly see how factorisations over the integers and different moduli relate to each other.
